# Getting Actual links from Google News RSS with PHP

Tags: php, rss

I want to parse Google News RSS with PHP, to get actual links of the content.

Google News RSS item link looks like this:

```
http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&usg=AFQjCNGkF58EwDE7aA742GfVP9aE8azmhg&url=http://www.reuters.com/article/2012/01/15/us-obama-mlk-idUSTRE80E0PD20120115
```

I need just the actual link, everything after ***&url=*** :

```
http://www.reuters.com/article/2012/01/15/us-obama-mlk-idUSTRE80E0PD20120115
```

And how would one go about eliminating the "non-essential" part of the URL, in essence targeting everything starting with ***http://news.google.com*** and ending with ***&url=*** ?

```
http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&usg=AFQjCNGkF58EwDE7aA742GfVP9aE8azmhg&url=
```

I do a little regex, but this is out of my reach...

Thanks, fellas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex is not necessarily the best approach here.

```
$query = parse_url($google_url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $parts);
$url = $parts['url'];
```

Comment: Thanks! And how would one go about eliminating the "non-essential" part of the URL (edited the question, to better explain)?

Comment: Actually, I think Francis' solution is better :)

Comment: What you want is in `$url` on the last line. You don't eliminate what you don't want, you get what you want and ignore the rest....

Answer (score 2):

Here ya go:

```
$google_url = 'http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&usg=AFQjCNGkF58EwDE7aA742GfVP9aE8azmhg&url=http://www.reuters.com/article/2012/01/15/us-obama-mlk-idUSTRE80E0PD20120115';
preg_match('/&url=([^&]+)/', $google_url, $matches);
$url = $matches[1];
echo $url;
```

Comment: Thanks! And how would one go about eliminating the "non-essential" part of the URL (edited the question, to better explain)?